# How to find the density of a conditional probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given a joint distribution $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, we know that the density condition on $X=x$ is $$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid X=x)=f_{X,Y}(x,y)/f_X(x)$$

On the other hand, I would like to find the density, if exists, given the condition involving two random variables, say $X=Y$ or $X+Y=k$.

For a concrete example, let $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=4xy$ on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. What is the density given $X=Y$?

I have tried to divide the original density by the probability of $X=Y$, but it seems awkward....

Do anyone have ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of slightly different ways you can think about this.

Firstly, it's helpful to rewrite the $f_X(x)$ term in the denominator of your conditional density as $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x, y) dy$ - that is, the integral over the joint density of the event you're conditioning on. By a similar token, the conditional density for $X$ conditional on $X=Y$ should be $f_{X,Y}(x,x)/\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X,Y}(t,t) dt$ - note that the denominator here isn't necessarily analytically available.

Another way you might like to think about this is to first apply a change of variables - instead of considering the pair of random variables $(X,Y)$, consider the pair $(X,Z)$, where $Z=X-Y$. You can write down the joint probability density function $f_{X,Z}(x,z)$ of $(X,Z)$, and now note that conditioning on $X=Y$ is exactly the same as conditioning on $Z=0$. So $f_{X\mid X=Y}(x) = f_{X\mid Z=0}(x) = f_{X,Z}(x,0) / f_Z(0)$.